# How to install linux-generic-hwe in ubuntu 17.10.1

Tags: drivers, apt, wireless

I freshly installed ubuntu 17.10.1 on my hp and my wifi seems to be not working. I searched for solution then i found `apt-get linux-generic-hwe-16.04` it throws an error **package not found**

i run this command

```
lspci -vnn | grep Network
```

output

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
```

`

Comment: The package you mention is available for 16.04 https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=linux-generic-hwe-16.04 which is why you get the error.   It lets 16.04 use the 17.10 kernel so I don't see it helping you anyway.  *Sorry I can't help with your issue*

Comment: @Jeremy31 thanx, my wifi is working now

Answer (score 2):

HWE Kernel is prepared only for LTS releases. Reference: [Ubuntu Wiki - LTS Enablement Stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack)

I would recommend waiting for 18.04 LTS release planned in this month and upgrade once.

Other option, check for [mainline kernel as explained here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade) which may work for you.